# How to prevent jQuery terminal plugin showing *** when typing a password in a password field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-terminal

I want to make the password field in jQuery terminal plugin the same as like the PuTTY password field, which will not show anything when we are entering a password. Currently, it is showing the password as "*****", but I don't want this type of behavior.
If anybody has done this before, or if you have any idea, please share.

Comment: You can use maskChar options default is this: `maskChar: '*'`  you can use any string including empty.

Comment: And you can also change mask in any time using `set_mask` if you use `.set_mask(true)` it will set mask to what ever you put into maskChar but you can overwrite it with string `.set_mask('-');` will set mask to dash (in fact it can be any string inlcuding the one that have more characters, you can use `"foo"`).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```js
$('body').terminal($.noop, {
  login: function(user, pass) {
    return fetch(`/auth?user=${user}&pass=${pass}`).then(r => r.text());
  },
  maskChar: ''
});
```

this will login to the server, (NOTE: the code use new fetch and template literals) here is the code with ES5 (but you still need fetch, if your browser don't support it, you can use [polyfill](https://github.com/developit/unfetch))

```js
$('body').terminal($.noop, {
  login: function(user, pass) {
    return fetch('/auth?user=' + user + '&pass=' + pass).then(function(res) {
       return res.text();
    });
  },
  maskChar: ''
});
```